# Allocation of dates with non renewable slots

Tags: python

I have a piece of code that is doing what I expect. My goal is to allocate to each 'structure' slot an equipping slot making sure equipping date >= structure date. Once an equipping slot is allocated, it can no longer be used by any other production slot.

Here is what I have done until now:

```
structure = {'type': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
             'model': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], 
             'end_week_mid_buffer': [10, 20, 25, 30, 35, 36, 37, 38]}
structure = pd.DataFrame(structure)

equipping = {'type': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
             'model': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], 
             'start_week': [5, 30, 35, 50, 36, 40, 41, 42]}
equipping = pd.DataFrame(equipping)


concat = pd.concat([structure, equipping])

def process_group(group):
    struc = group["end_week_mid_buffer"].dropna()
    equip = group["start_week"].dropna()
    if struc.empty or equip.empty:
        return None
    result = []
    for i in struc:
        valid_date = equip[equip >= i]
        if not valid_date.empty:
            result.append(equip[equip >= i].iloc[0])
            equip = equip[equip >= i].iloc[1:]

    if not result:
        return None

    data = {
        "struc": struc[: len(result)],
        "eq": result,
        "type": group["type"].iloc[0],
        "model": group["model"].iloc[0],
    }
    return pd.DataFrame(data)

df_total = (
    concat.groupby(["type", "model"], group_keys=False)
    .apply(process_group)
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

I get this result which is what I expect

```
struc   eq  type    model
0   10.0    30.0    1   a
1   20.0    35.0    1   a
2   25.0    50.0    1   a
3   35.0    36.0    2   a
4   36.0    40.0    2   a
5   37.0    41.0    2   a
6   38.0    42.0    2   a
```

Ideally, I would have joined the 'eq' date directly into the original structure dataframe instead of creating an intermediate df_total one, but I can still do a merge later on.

Can you think of a more efficient way of doing this? (vectorizing, using np or pd native functions, etc ... )
I am afraid that this will be slow for big datasets. Please note my dataset are always sorted by increasing dates.

please note that

```
merge_asof()
```

won't work as my equipping slots are non renewable resources: once used, they cannot be used again

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current approach is quite efficient and effective, especially given that your datasets are sorted by increasing dates. However, if you want to explore a more vectorized approach, you can use NumPy to improve the performance further:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

structure = {'type': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
             'model': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], 
             'end_week_mid_buffer': [10, 20, 25, 30, 35, 36, 37, 38]}
structure = pd.DataFrame(structure)

equipping = {'type': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
             'model': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], 
             'start_week': [5, 30, 35, 50, 36, 40, 41, 42]}
equipping = pd.DataFrame(equipping)

# Combine the DataFrames
combined = pd.concat([structure, equipping])

# Sort the combined DataFrame by 'end_week_mid_buffer' in ascending order
combined = combined.sort_values(by=['end_week_mid_buffer'])

# Initialize arrays for results
struc_dates = []
equip_dates = []

# Process the data
for _, group in combined.groupby(['type', 'model']):
    struc = group['end_week_mid_buffer'].values
    equip = group['start_week'].values
    equip_idx = 0

    for s in struc:
        while equip_idx < len(equip) and equip[equip_idx] < s:
            equip_idx += 1
        if equip_idx < len(equip):
            struc_dates.append(s)
            equip_dates.append(equip[equip_idx])
            equip_idx += 1

# Create a new DataFrame from the results
result = pd.DataFrame({'struc': struc_dates, 'eq': equip_dates})

print(result)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, this is a good news :)